# How to write custom function that also works with dplyr::across?

Tags: r, function, tidyverse, scoping, across

I've written some custom functions (see examples below) that work when using both, base R and within a dplyr::mutate pipe. However, I struggle getting it working dynamically with `dplyr::across`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
test1 <- function(data, column)
{
  if (!column %in% names(data))
  {
    stop("error in test1")
  }
  return(TRUE)
}

test2 <- function(data, column)
{
  check <- test1(data, column)
  
  if (check == TRUE)
  {
    my_sum <- sum(data[,column])
  }
  return(my_sum)
}

df <- data.frame(x = 1:5,
                 y = 11:15)

# Works    
test2(df, "x")

# Works
df |>
  dplyr::mutate(new_col = test2(df, "x"))

# Doesn't work
df |> 
  dplyr::mutate(across(c("x", "y"), ~test2(df, .)))

Error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(c("x", "y"), ~test2(df, .))`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `x`.
Caused by error in `test1()`:
! error in test1
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
Problem while computing `..1 = across(c("x", "y"), ~test2(df, .))`.
i the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Your function is a function of a data frame. `across` is used to apply functions to columns. Write your function so its expected argument is a vector, not a data frame, and it will work with `across`.

Comment: Like, the `mean` function takes a vector (column) and returns a value. So you can `mtcars %>% mutate(across(everything(), mean))` and it works, nice and simple. If you rewrote `mean` as taking a data frame, `my_mean <- mean(data, column) {mean(data[[column]])}` it would be a lot harder to use inside `across`, (or inside `mutate`) because `across` isn't made to pass the whole data frame into the function, just a single column.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I see the problem now. So bottomline: to make my functions "tidyverse-ready", I would need to rewrite them a lot/a bit.

Comment: See also here. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70402456/how-to-use-mutate-across-with-a-custom-function-with-multiple-arguments> The answer by @r2evans is conclusive and might help further.

Comment: @deschen to make your functions "tidyverse ready" in this case really just means making them base R functions that take a single vector as an argument. No need to over-complicate it or consider NSE etc.